# Hide span with tabindex

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to write "HIDE"-"SHoW" content only with css. But I need to hide + (class="span2") when I open paragraph under. How can I do it?

```css
p {
  display: block;
}
.question {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}
.alert {
  display: none;
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  position: relative;
}
.span2,
.span3 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <h1 align="left">More about/ Question</h1>
  <span class="span2" align="right" tabindex="0">+</span>


  <p class="alert">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vel sagittis metus, non commodo tortor. Donec vitae rutrum metus, a dictum nunc. Curabitur metus turpis, mattis sed libero vel, lacinia blandit nisl. Curabitur at accumsan ipsum, vitae
    vestibulum orci. Morbi accumsan dui odio, id varius mauris fermentum a. <span class="span3" align="right" tabindex="-1">-</span>
  </p>

</div>
```

So, I DONT WANT TO USE JAVA. Probably I should use active...or link span to h1 content and after write (display:none)...But I don't know :/

Comment: You've made it clear you don't want to use Java, but have you considered JavaScript?

Comment: I think he wants to use only CSS

Comment: Yep, NO JAVA.  I said it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of others solutions but you can use pseudo elements `:before` or `:after` in CSS to do the trick : [see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2862mtf0/4/)

```
.span2:before { content: "+"; }
.span2:focus:before { content: "";}
```

Comment: How not let text overflow on span?